# Why does standardizing normal distributions preserve probabilities?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Normalizing a normal distribution to the standrad normal distribution is achieved by creating from a random variable $X$ a new random variable $X' = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$, where $\mu$ is the mean of the distribution of $X$ and $\sigma$ is its standard deviation. I do understand why this does indeed yield the standard normal distribution. What I do not understand, is why $X'$ does have the same probabilities as $X$ or conversely, why all possible areas under the curve of $X'$ of given intervals on the x-axis stay the same as under the curve of $X$.

Sure, sliding the distribution around by subtracting $\mu$ does not alter the shape of the curve and thus all areas under the curve keep their original sizes. But why is that also true when stretchin gthe curve by dividing $X$ by $\sigma$?

Comment: The probabilities aren't the same....

Comment: If standardizing alters the probabilities then why even bother? What is the point if the original information is lost?

Comment: Assuming $b \gt 0$, then in general  $\mathbb P(X \le x) = \mathbb P\left(\frac{X -a}{b}  \le \frac{x -a}{b} \right) = \mathbb P\left(X'  \le \frac{x -a}{b} \right)$

Comment: Stretching the curve (when scaling $X$ by $\sigma$) retains the area under the curve because, by dividing, it's more likely that values will be closer to zero. So the density around zero will be larger and more compact, and vice versa when $\sigma < 1$, as [can be seen in the graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg). That the area under curve integrates to 1 you can check while following some proof and noting that the variance gets simplified (see Gaussian integral in wiki, i.e.), or by playing with numeric values on Wolfram.